# Template arguments error, C++

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I use a fairly complex data structure:

class 1:

```
template <class T>
class Number
{
private:
            T first;
            T second;

};
```

class 2:

```
template <typename Item>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};

template <typename Item>
class GList
{
private:
            typename TList <Item>::Type items;

public:
            GList() : items (0) {}


public:
            Item & operator [] (int index ) {return items[index];}
};
```

class 3:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class GList>
class sortIndices 
{

private:
    const GList <T> *l;

public:
    sortIndices ( const GList <T> *l_ ) : l ( l_ ) {}

    bool operator() ( const unsigned int &i_p1, const unsigned int &i_p2 ) const
    {
        return true;
    }

};
```

class 4:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class List>
struct TISet
{
    typedef std::set <unsigned int, sortIndices <T, List> >  Type;
};


template <typename T, template <typename> class List>
struct TSample
{
    T res;
    typename TISet <T, List> ::Type indices;
    TSample ( const List <T> *nl ) : res(0), indices ( nl ) {}
};
```

class 5:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class List>
struct TResults
{
    typedef std::set < TSample <T, List>, sortIndices <T, List> > Type;
};
```

class 6:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T, template <typename> class List>
    static void function (List <T> *l, typename TResults <T, List> ::Type *result) {}
};
```

The are problems using the following object as argument of the static function...

```
TResults <double, GList >::Type t_results;
```

My first question: How to  pass an address of the structure TResults correctly?

Main program:

```
int main() 
{
    GList <Number <double> *> plist; //Create list of numbers
    TResults <double, GList >::Type t_results; //Create empty results

    Test::function(&plist, &t_results); //ERROR, test function
}
```

Error code:

```
Error   1 error C2664: 'void Test::function< Number <T> *, GList>( GList <Item> *,std::set<_Kty, _Pr> *)' :
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::set<_Kty,_Pr> *' to 'std::set<_Kty,_Pr> *'

with
      [
          T=double,
          Item=Number<double> *,
          _Kty=TSample<Number<double> *,GList>,
          _Pr=sortIndices<Number<double> *,GList>
      ]
      and
      [
          _Kty=TSample<double,GList>,
          _Pr=sortIndices<double,GList>
      ]
      and
      [
          _Kty=TSample<Number<double> *,GList>,
          _Pr=sortIndices<Number<double> *,GList>
      ]
```

After modification

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T, template <typename> class List>
    static void function (typename TResults <T, List> ::Type *result) {}
};

int main() 
{
    GList <Number <double> *> plist; //Create list of numbers
    TResults <double, GList >::Type t_results; //Create empty results

    Test::function(&t_results); //ERROR, test function
}
```

There is the following error:

Error   1   error C2783: 'void Test::function(TResults::Type *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Thanks for your time and help...

Comment: After "cannot convert parameter 2 from blah to blah" VC will print what the template parameters listed actually are. If you can post that, too, we have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: The error mentions a type `Point<T>` that isn't shown anywhere in your code. What is it?

Comment: @sbi: Stop putting in the `<pre>` tags, it eats up the angle brackets in the code.

Comment: BTW, probably unrelated (I have not even finished understanding the question) but your code is incorrect in that `sortIndices` does not define a *strict weak ordering*, and that means that the behavior of the `set` is undefined.

Comment: @Ian: As far as I see the signature of `Test::function`,
shouldn't `plist`'s type be `GList<double>`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no matching specialization.  You could call

```
Test::function( GList<Number<double>*>*, TResults<Number<double>*, GList>::Type* );
```

or

```
Test::function( GList<double>*, TResults<double, GList>::Type* );
```

but the argument types you have don't go together.

Comment: It does not work, compiler says: Error C2059: syntax error : ','

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.ideone.com/tTETR

I changed types and added comparator parameter to `TResults::Type` ctor.